# How to validate YYYYMMDD date given as parameter PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, date, plsql

I have a SP called ADD_COMPLEX_SALE. It gets 4 parameters : custid, prod id, qty and date(varchar2).

I need to validate the date and check that it is in the right format. It is being sent to the procedure as YYYYMMDD.

This is what I have so far:

```
IF (LENGTH(pdate) != 8) THEN
    raise_application_error (-20093,' Date not valid');
ELSIF (LENGTH(pdate) = 8)THEN
    vDATE := CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), pdate(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD];
  END IF;

IF (pdate != 'YYYY/MM/DD') THEN
    raise_application_error (-20093,' Date not valid');
  END IF;
```

Basically the idea is too convert it to a 'real' date format so that I can know for sure it is in the proper format. Except I get this error. 
Still very new pl/sql so any help will be appreciated.

> Error(42,49): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

UPDATE:

Changed code to the following :

```
 vDATE := TO_DATE(pdate, 'yyyymmdd');
 IF (pdate != vDATE) THEN
   raise_application_error (-20093,' Date not valid');
 END IF;
 IF (LENGTH(vDATE) != 8) THEN
    raise_application_error (-20093,' Date not valid');
 END IF;
```

Now getting this error:

> ORA-20000: Another error occured ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

EDIT: Last update error was due to Parameter being varchar2 and me forgetting to INSERT vDATE instead of pdate after the conversion was done.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing or passing dates as `varchar`. Declaring the parameter as `date` is a much cleaner approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert(varchar(10), pdate(), 111)` appears to be an attempt to use the SQL Server `convert` function.  That's not going to work in Oracle.

I'd just do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_dt date;
BEGIN
  l_dt := to_date( pdate, 'yyyymmdd' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others
  THEN
    raise_application_error( -20001, pdate || ' is not a date in the format YYYYMMDD' );
END;
```

Of course, if you want to do multiple checks so that you can throw a different exception if the length is incorrect or add some checks to ensure that the date is reasonable (i.e. must be within the last 100 years or no more than 100 years in the future, etc.) you could do that after the `to_date` conversion.

Comment: How would I be able to incorporate it into a IF statement as I need to early raise the exception?

Comment: Getting the following error code now: _Adding Complex Sale - Customer ID: 10 Product ID: 2001 Date: 20140301 Qty: 60
ORA-20000: Another error occured ORA-01861: literal does not match format string_

Comment: @RietteJooste - Should have had a `when others`.  I was thinking of converting strings to numbers not dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DATECHECK(pdate VARCHAR2) AS
err_date EXCEPTION;
vdate DATE;
BEGIN

BEGIN
      vdate := to_date(pdate,'yyyymmdd');
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RAISE err_date;
    END;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN err_date THEN
    raise_application_error(-20090, 'DATE ERROR');
END;
```

Comment: I think only one exception handler would be sufficient.